# How to generate unique identifiers for functions, IDs: rating system

Tags: javascript, function, uniqueidentifier, rating

I am building a rating system where each selection contains a scale from 1 - 5, and -1 to -5. Depending on what you select on the scale, an input field is populated with the number, and the selection is highlighted.

What I want to do is repeat the process for up to 100 scales on the same webpage, without writing all the unique function and ID names for each.

What I have so far:

```js
   function changePlus1(value){
       document.getElementById("countPlus1").value = 1*value;
       var i;
       for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
         document.getElementById("selectPlus1"+[i]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);';
       }
       for (ii = -5; ii < 0; ii++) {
         document.getElementById("selectMinus1"+[ii]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);';
       }
       document.getElementById("selectPlus1" + value).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0);';
       document.getElementById("countMinus1").value = "";
   }
   function changeMinus1(value){
       document.getElementById("countMinus1").value = 1*value;
       var i;
       for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
         document.getElementById("selectPlus1"+[i]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);';
       }
       for (ii = -5; ii < 0; ii++) {
         document.getElementById("selectMinus1"+[ii]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);';
       }
       document.getElementById("selectMinus1" + value).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0); color:#fff;';
       document.getElementById("countPlus1").value = "";
   }
   function changePlus2(value){
       document.getElementById("countPlus2").value = 1*value;
       var i;
       for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
         document.getElementById("selectPlus2"+[i]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);';
       }
       for (ii = -5; ii < 0; ii++) {
         document.getElementById("selectMinus2"+[ii]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);';
       }
       document.getElementById("selectPlus2" + value).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0);';
       document.getElementById("countMinus2").value = "";
   }
   function changeMinus2(value){
       document.getElementById("countMinus2").value = 1*value;
       var i;
       for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
         document.getElementById("selectPlus2"+[i]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);';
       }
       for (ii = -5; ii < 0; ii++) {
         document.getElementById("selectMinus2"+[ii]).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);';
       }
       document.getElementById("selectMinus2" + value).style.cssText = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0); color:#fff;';
       document.getElementById("countPlus2").value = "";
   }
```

```css
<style>
    body {
        display:block; width:100%; height:100%; min-height:1000px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; background-color:#fff; top:0; left:0;
        }
    #selectPlus11, #selectPlus12, #selectPlus13, #selectPlus14, #selectPlus15,
    #selectPlus21, #selectPlus22, #selectPlus23, #selectPlus24, #selectPlus25 {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        height:40px; width:40px; margin:0 2px; border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2); color:#000; font-size:.85rem; font-weight:400;
    }
    #selectMinus1-1, #selectMinus1-2, #selectMinus1-3, #selectMinus1-4, #selectMinus1-5,
    #selectMinus2-1, #selectMinus2-2, #selectMinus2-3, #selectMinus2-4, #selectMinus2-5 {
        height:40px; width:40px; margin:0 2px; border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2); color:#000; font-size:.85rem; font-weight:400;
    }
    #countPlus1, #countMinus1,
    #countPlus2, #countMinus2 {
        height:40px; width:40px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; font-size:1.1rem; font-weight:700; border:0; border-bottom:3px solid #000;
    }
    #countPlus1,
    #countPlus2 {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
        background:none;
    }
    #countMinus1,
    #countMinus2 {
        display:block;
        float:right;
        margin-left:10px;
        background:none;
    }
    .bizModelRatingTableLabel {
        padding:0;
    }
    label {
        text-align:left;
        font-size:1rem;
    }
    table.bizModelRatingTable tbody tr td {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="countPlus1" value=""></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus15" type="button" onclick="changePlus1(5)" value="5"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus14" type="button" onclick="changePlus1(4)" value="4"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus13" type="button" onclick="changePlus1(3)" value="3"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus12" type="button" onclick="changePlus1(2)" value="2"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus11" type="button" onclick="changePlus1(1)" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="selectMinus1-1" type="button" onclick="changeMinus1(-1)" value="-1">
    <td><input id="selectMinus1-2" type="button" onclick="changeMinus1(-2)" value="-2">
    <td><input id="selectMinus1-3" type="button" onclick="changeMinus1(-3)" value="-3">
    <td><input id="selectMinus1-4" type="button" onclick="changeMinus1(-4)" value="-4">
    <td><input id="selectMinus1-5" type="button" onclick="changeMinus1(-5)" value="-5">
    <td><input type="text" id="countMinus1" value="">
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="countPlus2" value=""></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus25" type="button" onclick="changePlus2(5)" value="5"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus24" type="button" onclick="changePlus2(4)" value="4"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus23" type="button" onclick="changePlus2(3)" value="3"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus22" type="button" onclick="changePlus2(2)" value="2"></td>
    <td><input id="selectPlus21" type="button" onclick="changePlus2(1)" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input id="selectMinus2-1" type="button" onclick="changeMinus2(-1)" value="-1">
    <td><input id="selectMinus2-2" type="button" onclick="changeMinus2(-2)" value="-2">
    <td><input id="selectMinus2-3" type="button" onclick="changeMinus2(-3)" value="-3">
    <td><input id="selectMinus2-4" type="button" onclick="changeMinus2(-4)" value="-4">
    <td><input id="selectMinus2-5" type="button" onclick="changeMinus2(-5)" value="-5">
    <td><input type="text" id="countMinus2" value="">
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is merged the changePlus and changeMinus functions into one function, which accepts a sender (the element calling the function), and a value.

Based on whether the value is positive or negative we determine what the various styles should be, as well as what the sibling will be (pluses or minuses) and perform the necessary operations for all the elements (both positive and negative) of that group by traversing up two levels to get the row element, and finding the closest ancestor div element in order to find the appropriate sibling (previous for minuses, next for pluses) and then we go back down the sibling div and perform the changes on its children too.

We use the newly added classes to differentiate the various element types.

In the CSS, I changed the ID identifiers (#) to use class identifiers (.) which don't have to be unique, so we now add the appropriate class to all the elements.

In the HTML, apart from having added the classes and removing the unnecessary IDs, we also now send the element (this) as well as the value in the onclick property.

```js
   function changeValue(sender, value){
       var valueType1, valueType2, backgroundPlus, backgroundMinus, backgroundSelected, sibling, plusEls, minusEls;
       var row = sender.parentNode.parentNode;
       var parentDiv = row.closest('div');
       backgroundPlus = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);';
       backgroundMinus = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);';
       if (value > 0) {
           valueType1 = 'plus';
           valueType2 = 'minus';
           plusEls = row.querySelectorAll('.select-plus');
           minusEls = parentDiv.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.select-minus');
           sibling = parentDiv.nextElementSibling;
           backgroundSelected = 'background-color:rgba(0,255,0);';
       } else {
           valueType1 = 'minus';
           valueType2 = 'plus';
           plusEls = parentDiv.previousElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.select-plus');
           minusEls = row.querySelectorAll('.select-minus');
           sibling = parentDiv.previousElementSibling;
           backgroundSelected = 'background-color:rgba(255,0,0); color:#fff;';
       }
       row.querySelector(".count-" + valueType1).value = 1*value;
       plusEls.forEach(function(el) {
           el.style.cssText = backgroundPlus;
       });
       minusEls.forEach(function(el) {
           el.style.cssText = backgroundMinus;
       });
       sender.style.cssText = backgroundSelected;
       sibling.querySelector(".count-" + valueType2).value = "";
   }
```

```css
<style>
    body {
        display:block; width:100%; height:100%; min-height:1000px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; background-color:#fff; top:0; left:0;
        }
    .select-plus {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        height:40px; width:40px; margin:0 2px; border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2); color:#000; font-size:.85rem; font-weight:400;
    }
    .select-minus {
        height:40px; width:40px; margin:0 2px; border-radius:50%; background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.2); color:#000; font-size:.85rem; font-weight:400;
    }
    .count-plus, .count-minus {
        height:40px; width:40px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center; font-size:1.1rem; font-weight:700; border:0; border-bottom:3px solid #000;
    }
    .count-plus {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
        background:none;
    }
    .count-minus {
        display:block;
        float:right;
        margin-left:10px;
        background:none;
    }
    .bizModelRatingTableLabel {
        padding:0;
    }
    label {
        text-align:left;
        font-size:1rem;
    }
    table.bizModelRatingTable tbody tr td {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="count-plus" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 5)" value="5"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 4)" value="4"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 3)" value="3"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 2)" value="2"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 1)" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -1)" value="-1">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -2)" value="-2">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -3)" value="-3">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -4)" value="-4">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -5)" value="-5">
    <td><input type="text" class="count-minus" value="">
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="count-plus" value=""></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 5)" value="5"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 4)" value="4"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 3)" value="3"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 2)" value="2"></td>
    <td><input class="select-plus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, 1)" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="display:block; float:left; width:50%;">
<table class="bizModelRatingTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -1)" value="-1">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -2)" value="-2">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -3)" value="-3">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -4)" value="-4">
    <td><input class="select-minus" type="button" onclick="changeValue(this, -5)" value="-5">
    <td><input type="text" class="count-minus" value="">
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @alec1241 Pleasure! Glad to be of service!